# how to send windows dir output to git add

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, cmd

I want to add some file in folders and it's subfolders with special pattern to git in a batch file.

So **I can't** use "**git add --all**" or "**.**" because of my file pattern.
the files in that folders will change over the time, So I can't use specific file path to add them.
I have a command that's work fine in linux shell (like bellow)  :

```
git ls-files /back/git-back | grep '\.SQL$' | xargs git add
```

But, **I want command for windows command line**. I found something like this but it didnot work correctly.

```
dir /s /l /b *.SQL > git add
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: git accepts wildcards. Why you just don't use `git add **\*.SQL`  ?

Comment: thanks, it works for me.:) I don't know why I'm not use this? @npocmaka

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Two problems here (at least):

- The `>` character in shell commands (both in a POSIX shell
  (what you called "linux shell" but oh well, let's not digress),
  and in the Windows command interpreter, `cmd.exe`) stands for
  output redirection *to a file,* so the command

  ```
   dir ... > git add
  ```

  would have written the output of the `dir` command
  to a file named "git" in the current directory.

  The proper way to redirect the output of one command
  to the input of another (in both kinds of shells, too)
  is the "pipe" character, `|`.  But read forward.
- The `git add` command does not accept the list of
  files to update in the staging area on its standard input,
  nor does it have any command-line option to enable this behaviour.

  Hence using something like

  ```
  dir ... | git add
  ```

  would yield nothing anyway.

  The "trick" with `| xargs git add` worked for you simply because
  the way `xargs` behaves: it parses the data which comes on
  its input stream, breaks in it lines and then runs the specified
  command (`git add` in that case) with those lines passed to it
  as individual command line arguments, that is, if the part
  of that

  ```
  git ls-files ... | ... | xargs git add
  ```

  pipeline before the `xargs git add` would generate
  5 lines, the final call to `git args` arranged by `xargs` would
  look like

  ```
  git add line1 line2 line3 line4 line5
  ```

### The solutions

#### Save to a file, then do `dir /f`

The simplest one, I admit, is to roll as follows:

1. Save the output of the `dir` encantation to a file.
2. Make a loop over it—calling `git add` on each element.

   To do that, use the `for` command with the `/f` command-line
   argument—look for the section titled "Iterating a range of values
   " in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
   (you can also just run `for /?` and read the help.

   That would make it possible to assign a named variable
   of your choice to each file name read from the file in turn
   and then call `git add` on it.

#### Use `git update-index`

A more "hard-core" solution is to use a plumbing-level Git
command [`git update-index`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) (which is called by `git add`
in the end) as that command allows reading of the specifications
of how to update the staging area from its standard input stream.

The alleged problem with this approach is that you'd need
to post-process the output from `dir` to make it suitable
for what `git update-index` expects, and doing this in the
`cmd.exe`'s scripting language would be an exercise in futility.